# internet connection problem with windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, cable, internet-connection

I have just shifted to Windows 7 and I have this weird problem with the Internet connection.

First of all I had a cable connection and an ADSL router to connect to the Internet when I was using Windows XP. I had no problem but when I shifted to Windows 7 I have these problems.

- If I start the machine before connecting the router, even though all the indicator lights are glowing and indicating that I'm connected to Internet I can't connect using my web browsers as they always say that I cant' connect.
- Even though the router is connected when machine is starting, sometimes it connects but sometimes it won't work. But when I restart the machine the connection works, but it's very tedious to do that while I'm in the middle of working.

Can you guys suggest something to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can you have a cable Internet subscription working with a DSL router?

Comment: sorry cable subscription here in srilanka means the cable telephone line, not the cable subscription you are referring to your country, it's a local thing, sorry to put it like that! in our country we have two telephone connections, CDMA and telephone line connection, i was referring to telephone line connection when i stated cable connection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your network adapter settings.  Windows 7 can troubleshoot and automatically fix this for you.  Click the network icon in the lower right hand corner of the screen then click on open network and sharing center:
[image]

When you get to the network and sharing center if your not connected to the internet a red x will be displayed.  Just click it to start the automatic repair:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does your ISP **require** special software to be installed?  You may have had it on your Windows XP machine, and now you don't.

Comment: No it doesn't! when i got the router i just configured it with my data,that was provided by the ISP and connected it and started browsing!